# Iterm2 Preferences: Show bar with directory, date and git

Tags: terminal, iterm2, iterm

Sorry for the super basic question, but on a different computer, I have iTerm 2 setup so that it shows a bar at the top with the directory, the date and time and git branch. I recently set up a new computer and cannot figure out how to do it or where on preferences I set that up!

Does anyone have any idea what setting this is?

Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its just the status bar.

Go to **Preferences** -> **Profiles** -> **Select required profile** -> **Session** tab -> Check **Status bar enabled** checkbox -> Click **Configure Status Bar** and select 1. Current Directory 2. Clock 3. git state components.

You are all set.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much for finding it and for giving me the steps to setting it up.